# stored procedure and scheduled job return different data

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

Has anyone come across an issue where a stored procedure is run manually returns the correct data, but when you run the stored procedure inside a scheduled job it returns a different set of data??

Comment: Are you running it on the same machine? For instance if you try to pass a date as a param, maybe the calling machine has a different localle than the one on sql agent.

Comment: They run on the same machine, im really at a loss with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i tried scheduling the job in SSIS to trigger the stored proc, tried using SSIS data flows to replace the stored procedure and even creating the process on another server with the same result every time!

In the end what i have done is create an blank ssrs report that executes a stored procedure for a data set, then set a subscription to automatically run as if it was a normal report. Which in turn appears to mirror running the stored proc manually. job Done.

Would still love to sort this one properly though!